# What's the proper way to resize widgets in a layout?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyside

If I have a `QGridLayout` and stack two widgets on top of each other, then they take up 50% of the layout each. However, if one of the widgets is a `QLineEdit` widget, then that widget takes up a much smaller portion of the layout than 50%.

How do I add two widgets to a `QGridLayout`, then set the initial portions to something other than 50%/50%?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`QWidget.setSizePolicy`](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.setSizePolicy) to change layout behavior of the widgets. Default size policy is `QSizePolicy.Preferred`, which means that the widget can be freely resized, but prefers its "nature". For example `QLineEdit` does not resize vertically.

In this example button is set to expand vertically, filling the space and breaking the 50/50 layout:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.button = QPushButton("Test", self)
        self.button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.edit = QLineEdit(self)

        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.edit, 1, 0)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The default vertical size policy of `QLineEdit`is `QSizePolicy.Fixed`. That means it will always have the same height and other widgets might take available space in the layout.
So you might have to adjust the size policies of your widgets as Fenisko already demonstrated.

However if you have two or more expanding widgets in your layout, all will have equal size.
You can use `QGridLayout.setRowStretch(int column, int stretch)` and
`QGridLayout.setColumnStretch(int column, int stretch)` of your layout to adjust proportions of rows and columns.

Alterantively use `QSizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(int stretch)` and `QSizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(int stretch)` of your widget's size policies.